# Как заполнить input значением из select/option?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть пару `select`'ов. В первом я выбираю город и на основе этого строиться второй `select` с пунктами выдачи.

когда я выбираю значение из второго `select`'а с пунктами выдачи (`id="order_order_address_attributes_point_id"`), то `input` должен заполняться значением из выбранного `option`. Не `value`, а именно текстом

Как это можно реализовать?

Вот html

```
<tr>
  <td class="ltd">
    <label for="order_order_address_attributes_point_id">Пункт выдачи <i>*</i></label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <div class="boxberry">
      <select id="order_order_address_attributes_point_id">
         <option value="0">- выберите пункт -</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td class="ltd"></td>
  <td>
    <div class="ent-inp">
      <input id="order_order_address_attributes_point" size="30" type="text" value="">
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Вот скрипт:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#order_order_address_attributes_city').change(function () {
    var city_id = $(this).val();

    if (city_id == '0') {
      $('#order_order_address_attributes_point_id').html('<option>- выберите город -</option>');
      $('#order_order_address_attributes_point_id').attr('disabled', true);
      return(false);
    }

    $('#order_order_address_attributes_point_id').attr('disabled', true);

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: '/delivery.json',
      data: { code: city_id },
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(result) {
        var options = '<option>- выберите пункт -</option>'
        for (i=0;i<result.length;i++) {
          options += '<option value="' + result[i][1] + '">' + result[i][0] + '</option>';
        };

        $('#order_order_address_attributes_point_id').html(options);
        $('#order_order_address_attributes_point_id').attr('disabled', false);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C помощью функции [`.text()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/): Ее нужно использовать не от `<select>`, а от выбранного пункта, т.е. к селектору добавляем `:selected` (`option:selected`):

```js
$(function() {
  $('#select').on('change', function() {
    result = $('#select :selected').text();
    $('#input').val(result);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option value="1">Раз</option>
  <option value="2">Два</option>
  <option value="3">Три</option>
  <option value="4">Четыре</option>
  <option value="5">Пять</option>
</select>

<input id="input" val="" type="text" />
```